# create new column using differences of rows

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataset as below.

[image]

How can I create a new column B using the difference of values in A with matching ID. Apologies if this has been asked before. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, we can `group_by` `ID` and subtract `first` and `last` values of `A`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 summarise(B = first(A) - last(A), A = first(A)) %>%
 select(names(df), B)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  ID        A     B
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 aa        2    -1
#2 bb        4     0
#3 cc        3     1
#4 dd        1     0
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L
), .Label = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"), class = "factor"), A = c(2, 
4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to pivot the table so that the two 'A' values are in separate columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(name = if_else(duplicated(ID), "A_additional", "A")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID, values_from = A, names_from = name) %>% 
  mutate(B = A - A_additional)

# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#   ID        A A_additional     B
#   <fct> <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 aa        2            3    -1
# 2 bb        4            4     0
# 3 cc        3            2     1
# 4 dd        1            1     0
```

This solution doesn't require grouping, so should scale well to larger data sets.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(B = first(A) - last(A), A = first(A)), .(ID)]
```

data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L
), .Label = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"), class = "factor"), A = c(2, 
4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```